# How do kernel developers keep their code synchronized with the main kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

A question about organisation when developing own versions of the linux kernel:
How do developers synchronize their code with the main kernel code? I mean how do they integrate changes the main developers did?

Intuitively, I would think they initially would have cloned for example a git repository and then merge in changes from the main codebase in future. But I've seen some repos with modified kernels on github and did not see any signs of such synchronization.

Best regards.

Comment: Mostly all kernel maintainers will have the repo in https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/ and they accept patches from mainline list and merge it into their own tree. They won't sync with other maintainers repo usually. Their responsibility is to only sync with the maintainer whom they will send merge requests. For example, IIO maintainer Jonathan syncs with Greg repo before sending the final merged patches for a release. Maintainer also sends merge request directly to Linus main tree. In short, a Maintainer only cares about the hierarchy by which his/her merge goes to Linus tree.

Comment: repo in github are just mirrors. They won't be any manual intervention in sync. They are use web hooks to auto sync at scheduled time. You can assume something like cron job.

Comment: Between, this is not programming question!